# insert unit tests results from xml file to sonar database

Tags: unit-testing, maven, nant, sonarqube

I have project that is being built using NAnt.

Several projects are written in Delphi, several - C++, others - C#. They have unit tests. NAnt is smart enough to execute these unit tests.

As a result I have folder `TestsResults` containing one XML files (NUnit format) per one project with unit tests.

How can I insert tests results from these XML files into sonar DB? I tried to use Maven with sonar to do the trick but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the [Sonar .NET plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/.NET) details here? The [Delphi, C++ and C#](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Languages) are also documented.

Comment: Yes, I have read it. But maybe i have missed something. Besides I use NAnt, not ANT, and I think for performance reasons it would be better to run static code analysis using sonar-runner and then insert unit tests data from NUnit xml